# How to configure build command in Heroku's Clojure buildpack?

Tags: heroku, clojure, leiningen, ring, uberjar

Heroku is runnign `lein uberjar` to build my Clojure app, but I need it to run `lein ring uberjar`. Can this be configured without forking the buildpack?

I've tried setting the web process to just use `lein ring server-headless` to start, instead of the standalone jar, but then I get boot timeouts while dependencies are installing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clojure-support#customizing-the-build) there is the `LEIN_BUILD_TASK` configuration variable which you can set.

I'm assuming that setting it's value to `ring uberjar` should work for you.

If you check the source code of the [buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-clojure/blob/master/bin/compile#L35), the process fallbacks to `uberjar` when the `LEIN_BUILD_TASK` variable is not specified.